# Connecting Vb.net 2013 and Web into mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, web, connection

okay. before we begin our project I just want ask 
does the vb.net 2013 and web(online) can have a 1 database only one database(my sql)?
the name of our project is library system using barcode and the panel added a website for the user to reserved a book online
and the panel said that both system and the website must have only one database.. is that possible?

and before we begin what (mysql) database should i use in our system, what should i download in this site http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/  ??? do we need a sql connector ???

or can i use the mysql in wamp to connect both system and web? is that possible for vb.net 2013  and web?

I really lost about this,, so pls help me thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect any amount of items to a database provided that your server can handle the connections. All that is needed is the connection string to open a connection, then you need to handle data readers and the such (I prefer to use entity framework).

As for having only one database, think about what would happen if there were two databases. I go online, reserve the book in one database, but then you go to the physical library 5 minutes later and check out the book that I reserved because it does not show reserved in that database. See the problem? Both need to use the same database for book tracking or else you run into situations similar to what I just mentioned.

Comment: oh... thanks sir okay okay but what version of mysql should we download? mysql benchmark?

Comment: There is no 'benchmark'... There is a 'Workbench', but that is just a tool to facilitate working with the database. You will need a 'server' such as the 'MySql Community Server', but you will still need a computer to run this on (like a Server) that the applications will connect to. But you might run into legal problems using the 'Community' editions for a business so you might want to check that.

Comment: ohh sorry about that  ......they are 2 installer what should i download? it's confuse me cuz of the system we have online and the library system (vb.net)                                                               "If you have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-web-community file."                       and 
"If you do NOT have an online connection while running the MySQL Installer, choose the mysql-installer-community file."

Comment: i'm really sorry i'm new in this sql >_>

Comment: Web installer will download the items you want to install when you install them, the other will have everything in the installer. The Web version is preferable given you have an internet connection during installation.

Comment: last question, i click the developer default in the installation and so the Mysql server we will use as database both  system and web?